# What formula can I summarise for this relationship with x and y

Tags: linear-algebra, limits

I am doing a thesis about image processing and one of my finding is the relationship with two numbers. Now I want to summarise them into formula in order to easily calculate them. However, I am not sure which kind of formula or equation should I use for the following relationship:

I have $x$ ranging from 2 to 255, and $y$ value ranging from 0 to 30000. The relationship is like this:

> When $x$ equals 2 (the lowest value for $x$), I will get 30000 with
> $y$.
>
> When $x$ equals 255 (the highest value for $x$), I will get 0 in
> return with $y$.

So the relationship is pretty much about when $x$ gets larger, the $y$ value will correspondingly gets lower.

I currently assume they are linear relationship, how can I summarise a formula for this relationship.

Comment: You could use.
$$
y = \max\left[\min(g(x),30000),0\right]
$$
where 
$$
g(x) = a x + b
$$
you can use any function of $g$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you have two points (2, 30000) and (255, 0). Assumming linear relationships between x and y, the equation will be:

$\frac{y-0}{x-255} = \frac{30000-0}{2-255}$

$y = \frac{30000}{-253} (x - 255)$

$y = \frac{30000}{253} (255 - x)$.

You need to have more points to get higher degree equations.